# Where should Play! feature requests be submitted?

Tags: playframework

Should all feature requests be submitted under [Play 2.0](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview) in Lighthouse, or under [Play Framework](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/overview) (Play 1.X is in maintenance mode)?

Is there something I should do to mark a ticket as a feature request rather than a bug? I didn't find any way to do this, but I *think* I found one ticket that was marked as a feature request somehow.

Should I also post to the Google Group after submitted a feature request?

Comment: It's better to ask this kind of things on the Play Framework groups, and not on StackOverflow. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Jonas - you might be right. Play chose to direct all questions about itself to Stack Overflow, but some part of these questions might not be classified as strictly "programming questions". However, they're questions _about_ a programming framework, so they might still be considered On Topic. I won't delete the question myself (if people feel the need to close it as Off Topic, be my guest)

Comment: Asked on the group as well, in case this gets closed: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Jce7LsfG8BQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's off-topic (and will probably be closed), but the best way would be to post the suggestion in the Google Group, so it can be discussed by the community and then (if deemed useful) added to the roadmap ofr a future Play 2.x release.

Another option is to do a pull request in Git with the patch including the feature, but Play devs advised not to do so yet as Play 2.x is still under heavy development, and they will probably ignore them until release (maybe sooner, who knows!).

Comment: Ah, until now I just submitted bugs and issues to the issue tracker and assumed someone will read them :) How about posting an issue, and then posting it to the user group - wouldn't that be preferable to just a post in the group, that might get lost in the flood?

Comment: Yes, that can be good, but it may work the other way around too: if the proposal is good there will be support/discussion around it and the issue raised might have more success. Either way should work